# Apache Virtualhost Directory conditional redirect

Tags: apache, http-redirect, virtual-server

I just created a website with two environments as virtualservers - testing and production. As production server is open to everyone but I allowed only my IP to access testing environment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/xxx/www
    ServerName testing.xxx.com
    <Directory /home/xxx/www>
        Order deny, allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that google has already indexed some of my testing environment pages and they are available in google results. I would like any IP but mine to be redirected to production server (xxx.com) while accessing testing.xxx.com. I would rather do it with `apache.conf` than `.htaccess`(because of git repositories conflicts). Is it possible to add a conditional redirect to apache config?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mod_rewrite` features in your `httpd.conf` Apache config file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\.788 [OR] # exclude your first IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\.789 # exclude your second IP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://production-env.com/$1 [R=301,L] # redirection to production site

</IfModule>
```

Or you can put these declarations into `<Directory>` section of your vhosts config file.

Generally you can take advantage of `mod_rewrite` module to manage URL routing policies for your web server. Before using it make sure that this module is installed and activated in your Apache.